# How do i check database table through datatable and extract information of another column of database table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I was trying to check whether there is any rows having username and friend username in database table. If any then I have to take the friendship status in a string and will return that string.
Here is the code:

```
string query = "Select * from tblfriend where username = '" + username + "'and friend = '" + friendname + "'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

rows = dt.Rows.Count;

if (rows > 0)
{
    friendship = reader["friendshipstatus"].ToString();
}
```

But it gives a error message:

> Invalid Call to call MetaData when reader is closed.
>   Can you guys please give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading DataTable from same reader it may be closed after the loading complete.

As Side node, you better use parameters, using statements etc like below

```
string queryString = "Select [friendshipstatus] from [tblfriend] where [username] = @username and [friend] = @friend";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@friend", friendname );

    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(reader.Read()) // you have matching record if this condition true 
        {
            friendship = reader.GetString(0); // get the value of friendshipstatus 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the reader to populate data table and then when it had already been used for that - attempt to use it again.

There are better ways to retrieve single value from db (look up ExecuteScalar) but to make your current code work replace the last line with

`friendship = dt.rows[0].["friendshipstatus"].ToString()`

This will get the data from the data table you populated instead of closed reader.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dataadapter if you want to read data into table

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// Create new DataAdapter
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
{
   // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable     
   a.Fill(dt);
   // read data here
}
rows = dt.Rows.Count;
if (rows > 0)
{
     friendship = dt.Rows[0]["friendshipstatus"].ToString();
}
```